# "cannot find module providing for package" in go

Tags: docker, go

Im trying to install the official go docker client by importing

"github.com/docker/docker/client"

But i get the following error

cannot load github.com/docker/distribution/reference: cannot find module providing package github.com/docker/distribution/reference

My go version is 1.12 and
my project is outside $GOPATH/src. My go.mod file looks like this.

```
module app

go 1.12

require (
  github.com/Microsoft/go-winio v0.4.14 // indirect
  github.com/docker/docker v1.13.1
  github.com/docker/go-connections v0.4.0 // indirect
  github.com/docker/go-units v0.4.0 // indirect
  golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190827160401-ba9fcec4b297 // indirect
)
```

Comment: Try updating the version of `github.com/docker/docker`.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that I had similar problems as you 1.5-2 monthes ago.

**My observations**:

- there are a lot of versions of docker API
- it's hard to tell which version described in "official" documentation
- API itself flawed
- source code  - quite easy to understand

I did not found answers for "what actually describes official documentation?" or  "where actually docker API repo?"

I gave up on attempts to solve in "official way" and found that more practical to use "unofficial"

**"Unofficial way"**:

- use [docker/docker-ce](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/tree/master/components/engine)  (note that examples from official documentation will not work without modification)
- instead of official documentation - just search code in `docker-ce` repo.
- best example of `docker/client` usage I found here: [components/engine/integration/internal/container/exec.go](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/e3af8e077494c6a2b8b4f8a4a979b559825e8f7a/components/engine/integration/internal/container/exec.go#L13) (note that it resides in `internal` and is impossible to be used as package)
- I grabbed code that I needed into my package and solved the problem I had

Maybe it's "incorrect" solution but it worked for me.

I suppose it could be more practical for you to not rely on docker documentation too.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Based on [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/), it says that you have to execute `go get github.com/docker/docker/client` command to download it. Once library is retrieved it should compile.

Comment: For the sake of posting here I put app but it's exactly like GitHub.com/my/repo. Plus why should that even matter ? Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Sorry for answer I have provided above. I see that the cause of the problem is not existing source code repository. github.com/docker/docker  url automatticaly redirects to https://github.com/moby/moby repository. Where did you get the source from?

Comment: This is the official client for docker, it's on goDoc

Comment: Ok. Based on information you have provided I see that documentation [https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/] says that you have to execute `_go get github.com/docker/docker/client` command to download it. Once library is retrieved it should compile. I have updated original answer.